# Adding a layout to a Viewgroup.

Tags: android, layout, view, viewgroup

My issues is the following I'm trying to add a layout to a viewgroup my code goes like this:

```
View Dyn =  (View) findViewById(R.id.lca1);

ViewGroup Layout1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.l1);

View inflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.id.lcar1, null);
Layout1.addView(inflatedView);
```

My Logcat:

> 08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.ViewFlipperExample}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f05002a type #0x12 is not valid
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f05002a type #0x12 is not valid
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8667)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at com.test.ViewFlipperExample.onCreate(ViewFlipperExample.java:66)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   08-05 19:01:02.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26934):     ... 11 more

Any Help with this would help.
Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View inflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.id.lcar1, null); is wrong
you should inflate layout from res/layout folder (R.layout.lcar1 for example or any other)